# Reading Wrong Value from ASP.NET DropDownList Control

Tags: asp.net, webforms, html-select, postback

I'm having problems with a DropDownList control (see below) on an ASP.NET webform.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_Approved" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="No">No</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value"NA">n/a</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I read the value for the control from a database, which is either "Yes", "No", or "NA" (saved in approvedText), and then set this as the "selected" value in the control with the following code:

```
DropDownList_Approved.SelectedIndex = DropDownList_Approved.Items.IndexOf (DropDownList_Approved.Items.FindByValue (approvedText));
```

I used the following code to read the selected value of the control for saving it to the database:

```
string approved = DropDownList_Approved.SelectedValue;
```

The problem is that at this point, no matter what dropdown option is selected, the first item ("No") is what gets saved back to the database. But this only occurs when I set the selected item in the dropdownlist at PageLoad. If I don't use the "DropDownList_Approved.SelectedIndex" code, the value that gets saved to the database is the dropdown SelectedValue.

What am I doing wrong in the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Dropdown list value in `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` in `Page_Load` block.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    // Set dropdown value from database
}
```

Whenever Button click event is called it call the `Page_Laod` first so it reset the current selected value with the one which is set on the page load from database.